# Is every union-closed family of set the set of solutions of some co-HORNSAT formula?

Tags: lo.logic

Related to the Union-closed sets conjecture.

Let $\phi$ be a [co-HORNSAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn-satisfiability)
on variables $x_1 \ldots x_n$ in CNF format.
This means in every close at most one literal is negative.

The solutions of $\phi$ are closed under disjunction,
which is related to set union.

Map the $j$-th solution $y_1 \ldots y_n$ to a set $S_j$,
$i \in S_j$ iff $y_i$ is True.

The inverse map is $y_i \iff (i \in S_j)$.

The sets $S_j$ corresponding to the solutions of $\phi$
are closed under union, so Frankl's conjectures implies
in $\phi$ there is variable $x_i$ which is True in 
at least half the solutions.

> Is the converse true:  to every union-closed family of
>   sets $S_i$ corresponds a co-HORNSAT formula whose solutions
>   are the mapped $S_i$?

From certain co-HORNSAT formulae got sets in which
all elements are in exactly half the sets.

The powerset might cause difficulty so either exclude it
or allow clauses of the form $x \lor \lnot x$.

Comment: Every intersection-closed family, i.e., a closure operator, can be axiomatized by Horn formulas, and yours is just the dual. Take the conjunction of all co-Horn clauses that are valid in every $S_i$, then showing that this works is a simple exercise.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Thanks! Do you mean: map S_i to clause, compute the truth table and convert to CNF. Take the conjunctions. This might be not co-Horn, but some minimization must make it co-Horn?

Comment: I mean exactly what I wrote: take the set of all co-Horn clauses $C$ with the property that for every $i$, the assignment corresponding to the set $S_i$ satisfies $C$. I don’t quite understand what you are saying, as $S_i$ is not the solution set of a clause to begin with, but yes, you are essentially asking for a conversion of a full DNF (whose disjuncts are essentialy the sets $S_i$) with some property to a co-Horn CNF.

Comment: Thanks, I was wrong, it is indeed DNF. I think mine will work too.

Comment: Knuth has a program Horncount on his webpages.  I don't think he talks about union-closed set systems, but he does talk about closure operators.  You might check it out: it counts those systems on a base set of six elements.

Comment: There is also https://oeis.org/A102897 if you want the enumeration sequence.

Comment: @TheMaskedAvenger thanks. In terms of coHorn how a minimal counterexample would look like? I suspect one must maximize the negative literals, so this would mean all clauses are binary with one negative literal.

Comment: If you mean a representation of a (non-Frankl) union closed finite set family encoded as a conjunction of Horn clauses, the only example I know of is TRUE (or maybe I mean FALSE).

Comment: @TheMaskedAvenger Thanks. Horn gives set intersection which is equivalent. Your example leads to the empty set IMHO and this is excluded in Frankl's (missed this in the OP).